# Multi-dimensional menu hover question

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have just started making [a wp-site](http://johanberntsson.se/dev/fysiosteo/).

I have a small problem with the menu though; I want the main menu to stay active while your hovering the children. For example, when you hover "Undersida 1" under "Hem", I want "Hem" to keep its `backgroundcolor`.

Comment: word-press website probably :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem with the following change in your CSS:

you should use "li:hover a" instead of "li a:hover":

```
#menu-main-menu li:hover a {
    background: #afffaf;
}
```

The reason this should work is that even when u are on the sub-menu li:hover is still considered as active stylesheet but not "li a:hover".

Comment: followup-question: can i make it keep the same background-color until my animation is complete?

Comment: for that you need to add classes before and after animation using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use the method addClass? Then give that class a background-color.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to select the element that im talking about. Something like  $(this).parent('li')... i guess